# How can I remove unused string resource items in a simple way in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

I know I can use the shortcuts **Ctrl+Alt+O** to remove needless Import in Android Studio.

Now there are many string resource names in my resource files, such as **strings.xml**, but some string resource names are nerver used in my project.

Is there a simple way to remove these unused string resource names.

At present I have to delete the item `<string name="ExpiredWarning">Warning</string>` manually  if I found I don't need it again.

**Strings.xml**

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">Screen Recorder</string>



    <string name="BtnBuy">Purchase</string>
    <string name="BtnRetrieve">Retrieve</string>
    <string name="BuyPrompt">This is a trial version. It will be fully functional for 15 days. You can upgrade to the unlimited version and remove banner ads via an in-app purchase.</string>
    <string name="RetrievePrompt">If you have purchased the app, please click \'Retrieve\' button to recover.</string>
    <string name="MsgBillError">Problem setting up in-app billing: </string>
    <string name="MsgBillINI">An error occurred when initialize billing!</string>
    <string name="MsgOrderError">Purchasing error: </string>
    <string name="MsgOrderOK">You have purchased successfully! Please close and restart the app !</string>
    <string name="MsgInventoryFail">Failed to query inventory: </string>
    <string name="MsgRetrieveOK">You have retrieved your order info successfully! Please close and restart the app !</string>
    <string name="MsgRetrieveFail">You havn\'t purchased the app, please click \'Purchase\' button</string>
    <string name="ExpiredWarning">Warning</string>
    <string name="ExpiredTitle">The app expired, you can upgrade to the unlimited version and remove banner ads via an in-app purchase.</string>

</resources>
```

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/29148927/3134215

Comment: Thanks! But what I need is to remove unused items in resource files

Answer (score 7):

Simple solution is

From top bar select **Refactor -> Remove Unused Resources**

Comment: You dont have to open strings.xml for that

Comment: @TimCastelijns I have updated answer :) Thanks for correcting