# How to perform safe delete of string resources?

Tags: android, string

I have an unused string resource in `strings.xml`. I want to **"Safe Delete"** this resource so that it removes this string resource from all the strings.xml (of different languages) files.

How to do this with Android studio?

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer from this link :
[How to delete an unused string resource for all configurations in Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28937562/how-to-delete-an-unused-string-resource-for-all-configurations-in-android-studio)

Answer that worked for me :
To Delete a single string resource across all locale files, you can use the "Translation Editor". 1. Right click on the res directory to open the translation editor. 2. Select "Show All Keys" selector, and choose "Filter by Text". Supply the name of the resource that you want to delete. 3. Select the resource, and click on the "-" button